# How to set a checkbox status as True / False within a IF-THEN statement using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, checkbox, silktest

I am trying to automate a scenario using silk test and am very new to coding using vb.net. Basically i have a checkbox identified and want to set it to either true or false based on a string value being passed.

for e.g.

```
Dim tfnSigned As String
tfnSigned = "Yes"
If tfnSigned = "Yes"
Then .CheckBox("SED_TFNSignedCheckBox").Check
End If
```

In this case, i get a compiler error as .CheckBox is not identified as a class and hence cannot use the Check method

Kindly help

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`Checkboxes` accepts only `Boolean` values which is either `True or False`.

The syntax is pretty much straightforward and can be easily found on `Google`

Here I assume that `SED_TFNSignedCheckBox` is the name of your checkbox control.

```
Dim tfnSigned As String
tfnSigned = "Yes"

If tfnSigned = "Yes" Then
     SED_TFNSignedCheckBox.Checked = True
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the .Checkbox() method you need to be in the correct context, i.e. it should appear in a **With..End With** statement.  the best way to get the syntax correct is to use the Silk Test Recorder to record a checking the checkbox, this will generate something like this.

```
With _desktop.Dialog("locator of dialog")
   .CheckBox("SED_TFNSignedCheckBox").Check
End With
```

So your complete code would look something like this ...

```
Dim tfnSigned As String
tfnSigned = "Yes"
If tfnSigned = "Yes" Then
  With _desktop.Dialog("locator of dialog")
    .CheckBox("SED_TFNSignedCheckBox").Check
  End With
End If
```

Hope that helps.